# ClassCastException / ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException by trying to make a RecyclerView to handle multiple types of viewholder

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I've a problem with my RecyclerView. Let me explain the problem in detail. I try to implement a RecylerView with four different kinds of child views. I followed a how-to from "[Double Wong](http://doublewong.com/2014/create-recyclerview-with-multiple-view-type/)". So basically I have four ViewHolders extended from one main ViewHolder, at the onCreateViewHolder() I choose which one of them should be initialized. For this I override the getItemViewType() Method. It works fine, as long as all childs are of type 0. (type 0 means the item is not in the database, type 1 - 3 means different flags in the database).

Sometimes I get an **ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException** and sometimes it is a **ClassCastException**, **I cant figure out a pattern**.
Here comes my Code, I made some cuts to make it shorter.

### The Fragment

```
public class SucheSerienFragment extends Fragment {
...
    public List<Pair<SerieInfo, Integer>> listTvShows;
    private SerieCardViewSucheAdapter serieCardViewSucheAdapter;
...

private class LoadSerie extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... search) {
           ...
                        int type;
                        if (db.checkSerie(serieInfo)) {
                            serieInfo = db.getSerieByName(serieInfo.getName());
                            if (serieInfo.getArchivFlag() == 0){
                                type = SucheMainViewHolder.TYPE_AT_WATCHLIST;
                            } else if (serieInfo.getArchivFlag() == 1) {
                                type = SucheMainViewHolder.TYPE_PAUSIERT;
                            } else if (serieInfo.getArchivFlag() == 2) {
                                type = SucheMainViewHolder.TYPE_ABGESCHLOSSEN;
                            }  else {
                                type = SucheMainViewHolder.TYPE_SEARCH;
                        } } else {
                            type = SucheMainViewHolder.TYPE_SEARCH;
                        }

                        final SerieInfo finalSerieInfo = serieInfo;
                        final int finalType = type;

                        getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                listTvShows.add(new Pair(finalSerieInfo, finalType));
                                serieCardViewSucheAdapter.notifyItemInserted(serieCardViewSucheAdapter.getItemCount() - 1);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            } catch (TVDBOutboundConnectionException e1) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Es konnte keine Verbindung aufgebaut werden");
                Log.e(TAG, "Error" + e1);
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            return "Executed";
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String string) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onPostExecute");
            progressBarLoadSerie.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            if (listTvShows.isEmpty()) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Keine Serie gefunden", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                nothingFoundFrameLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            Log.d(TAG, "onPreExecute");
            progressBarLoadSerie.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onPrograessUpdate");
        }
    }
```

### SucheMainViewHolder

```
public class SucheMainViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        public static final int TYPE_SEARCH = 0;
        public static final int TYPE_AT_WATCHLIST = 1;
        public static final int TYPE_PAUSIERT= 2;
        public static final int TYPE_ABGESCHLOSSEN= 3;


        public SucheMainViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super ( itemView );
        }
    }
```

### SucheAbgeschlossenHolder

```
public class SucheAbgeschlossenHolder extends SucheMainViewHolder {
    public TextView tvSerienName;
    public TextView tvCurrentEpisode;
    public ImageView tvSerienImage;
    public RelativeLayout linearBackground;
    public ImageView imgViewSerie;
    public ImageButton playButton;
    public ImageButton deleteButton;
    public ImageButton abschliesButton;

    public SucheAbgeschlossenHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        tvSerienName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvSerienName);
        tvCurrentEpisode = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvSerienOverview);
        tvSerienImage = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imgViewSerie);
        linearBackground = (RelativeLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.rla);
        playButton = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.playImageButton);
        deleteButton = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.deleteImageButton);
        abschliesButton = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.abschliesenImageButton);

        imgViewSerie = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imgViewSerie);
    }
}
```

### SuchePausiertHolder

```
SuchePausiertHolder extends SucheMainViewHolder {

    public TextView tvSerienName;
    public TextView tvCurrentEpisode;
    public ImageView tvSerienImage;
    public RelativeLayout linearBackground;
    public ImageView imgViewSerie;
    public ImageButton playButton;
    public ImageButton deleteButton;
    public ImageButton abschliesButton;

    public SuchePausiertHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        tvSerienName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvSerienName);
        tvCurrentEpisode = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvSerienOverview);
        tvSerienImage = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imgViewSerie);
        linearBackground = (RelativeLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.rla);
        playButton = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.playImageButton);
        deleteButton = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.deleteImageButton);
        abschliesButton = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.abschliesenImageButton);

        imgViewSerie = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imgViewSerie);
    }
```

}

### SucheSerieViewHolder

```
public class SucheSerieViewHolder extends SucheMainViewHolder{


         public TextView tvSerienName;
         public TextView tvSerienOverview;
         public TextView tvRating;
         public ImageView tvSerienImage;
         public  ImageButton btnAddSerie;
         public  LinearLayout linearSerienSucheBackground;

        public SucheSerieViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            tvSerienName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvSerienName);
            tvSerienOverview = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvSerienOverview);
            tvSerienImage = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imgViewSerie);
            btnAddSerie = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.btnAddSerie);
            linearSerienSucheBackground = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.linearSerienSuche);
            tvRating = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvRating);
        }

}
```

### SucheWatchedHolder

```
  public class SucheWatchedHolder extends SucheMainViewHolder {
        public TextView tvSerienName;
        public TextView tvCurrentEpisode;
        public ImageView tvSerienImage;
        public View btnNext;
        public RelativeLayout linearBackground;
        public ImageView imgViewSerie;

        public SucheWatchedHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            tvSerienName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvSerienName);
            tvCurrentEpisode = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvSerienOverview);
            tvSerienImage = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imgViewSerie);
            btnNext = (View) v.findViewById(R.id.btnNext);
            linearBackground = (RelativeLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.rla);
            imgViewSerie = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imgViewSerie);
        }  }
```

### SerieCardViewSucheAdapter

```
 @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) >{
        LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from ( >viewGroup.getContext () );

        int type = getItemViewType(viewType);
        switch (type) {
            case SucheMainViewHolder.TYPE_SEARCH:
                ViewGroup vSuche = ( ViewGroup ) mInflater.inflate ( >R.layout.cardview_serie_suche, viewGroup, false );
                SucheSerieViewHolder vhSuche = new SucheSerieViewHolder ( >vSuche );
                return vhSuche;
            default:
                vSuche = ( ViewGroup ) mInflater.inflate ( >R.layout.cardview_serie_suche, viewGroup, false );
                vhSuche = new SucheSerieViewHolder ( vSuche );
                return vhSuche;
            case SucheMainViewHolder.TYPE_AT_WATCHLIST:
                ViewGroup vSucheWatched = ( ViewGroup ) mInflater.inflate ( >R.layout.cardview_serie, viewGroup, false );
                SucheWatchedHolder vhSucheWatched = new SucheWatchedHolder >( vSucheWatched );
                return vhSucheWatched;
            case SucheMainViewHolder.TYPE_PAUSIERT:
                ViewGroup vSuchePausiert = ( ViewGroup ) mInflater.inflate >( R.layout.cardview_serie_pausiert, viewGroup, false );
                SuchePausiertHolder vhSuchePausiert = new >SuchePausiertHolder ( vSuchePausiert );
                return vhSuchePausiert;
            case SucheMainViewHolder.TYPE_ABGESCHLOSSEN:
                ViewGroup vSucheAbgeschlossen = ( ViewGroup ) >mInflater.inflate ( R.layout.cardview_serie_abgeschlossen, viewGroup, false );
                SucheAbgeschlossenHolder vhSucheAbgeschlossen= new >SucheAbgeschlossenHolder( vSucheAbgeschlossen );
                return vhSucheAbgeschlossen;

        }



    }
...
     @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {
            final SerieInfo serieInfo = listSerieInfo.get(position).first;
            if (viewHolder == null) {
                return;
            }
            switch (viewHolder.getItemViewType()) {
                default:
                   ...
                    return;
                case SucheMainViewHolder.TYPE_SEARCH:
                  ...
                    return;
                case SucheMainViewHolder.TYPE_AT_WATCHLIST:
                    ...
             return;
                case SucheMainViewHolder.TYPE_PAUSIERT:
                   ...
                    return;
                case SucheMainViewHolder.TYPE_ABGESCHLOSSEN:
                   ...
                    return;
            }


         }

...

     @Override
         public int getItemViewType(int position) {
             return listSerieInfo.get(position).second;
         }
```

### IndexOutOfBoundsException

```
06-01 00:49:17.327  23289-23289/com.turnonandroid.seriencounter E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.turnonandroid.seriencounter, PID: 23289
    java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1, size is 1
            at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
            at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
            at com.turnonandroid.serienmanager.Adapter.SerieCardViewSucheAdapter.getItemViewType(SerieCardViewSucheAdapter.java:390)
            at com.turnonandroid.serienmanager.Adapter.SerieCardViewSucheAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(SerieCardViewSucheAdapter.java:359)
            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:5062)
            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4368)
            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4278)
            at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:1947)
            at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1359)
            at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1322)
            at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:556)
            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:2673)
            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:2971)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16552)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5355)
            at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1070)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16552)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5355)
            at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1070)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16552)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5355)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:335)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:272)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16552)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5355)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:335)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:272)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16552)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5355)
            at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1070)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16552)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5355)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:335)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:272)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16552)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5355)
            at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:493)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16552)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5355)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:335)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:272)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16552)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5355)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1707)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1561)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1470)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16552)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5355)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:335)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:272)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16552)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5355)
            at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:907)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16552)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5355)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:335)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:272)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16552)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5355)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRoo
```

### ClassCastException

```
06-01 00:56:09.436  27453-27453/com.turnonandroid.seriencounter E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.turnonandroid.seriencounter, PID: 27453
    java.lang.ClassCastException: com.turnonandroid.serienmanager.SucheSerieViewHolder cannot be cast to com.turnonandroid.serienmanager.SucheWatchedHolder
            at com.turnonandroid.serienmanager.Adapter.SerieCardViewSucheAdapter.onBindViewHolder(SerieCardViewSucheAdapter.java:167)
            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:5084)
            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4385)
            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4278)
            at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:1947)
            at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1359)
            at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1322)
            at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.scrollBy(LinearLayoutManager.java:1150)
            at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.scrollVerticallyBy(LinearLayoutManager.java:1007)
            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.scrollByInternal(RecyclerView.java:1355)
            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onTouchEvent(RecyclerView.java:2209)
            at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:9244)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2536)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2229)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2542)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2243)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2542)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2243)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2542)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2243)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2542)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2243)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2542)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2243)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2542)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2243)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2542)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2243)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2542)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2243)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2542)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2243)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2542)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2243)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2542)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2243)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2542)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2243)
            at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2392)
            at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1730)
            at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2710)
            at android.support.v7.internal.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:59)
            at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2353)
            at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:9439)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4181)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4047)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3593)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3646)
```

---

Thank you for reading and thinking about my Problem.

Comment: We are gonna need the crashes to see where they are happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so I fixed the Problem by going a different way. So instead of adding different kinds of ViewHolders there is just one. Which includes all kinds of ViewHolders (in the layout) but with the visibility GONE. In the onBindViewHolder() method I check which type should be shown and set the visibility to VISIBLE. It's probably not the best way (maybe the worst) but for me its working.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so about the `IndexOutOfBoundsException`, you should check your `getItemCount()` in the adapter. If you are calling `listSerieInfo.get(position)` in `getViewType()`, the method should look like this:

```
return listSerieInfo != null ? listSerieInfo.size() : 0;
```

About the `ClassCastException`, you have to move the `default` option in `onBindViewHolder` to the bottom. It should always be there.

Comment: thanks for your fast answer. Moving default to the button seems to fix the ClassCastException. But there is still a problem with getItemViewType(). I don't get an IndexOutOfBoundsException, but the type of all childs are the same now (always the type from the last child)

Comment: Hmm I see you have two switch blocks. Make sure you've moved both default clauses to the bottom.

Comment: thanks again, I moved both default blocks to the bottom

Comment: Well so the only thing I can think of right now is that you should check if listSerieInfo.get(position).second is actually returning the right type.